# Exact Bash equivalent for CMD dir /b

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin, ls

In the Windows command prompt, `dir /b > List.txt` prints a linebreak-separated list of the contents of a directory to a text file:

```
Folder 1
Folder 2
Folder 3
File 1.txt
File 2.txt
File 3.txt
```

In `bash` on Cygwin, doing `ls > File.txt` produces the following:

```
Folder 1Folder 2Folder 3File 1.txtFile 1.txtFile 2.txt
```

Bash doesn't seem to default to printing entries on their own line, and neither `ls -h` nor `ls -1` seem to make any difference to this. Also, seeing the `-a` option makes me worried about what results are being shown - do I need to call `-a` to see all of the results that would ordinarily be shown using `dir /b` in `CMD`, or simply to see those that I wouldn't have seen in `CMD`?

How do I do the exact equivalent of `dir \b` in Bash?

Comment: Unlike how `dir` is builtin to `cmd`, the `ls` command isn't builtin to `bash`. They're two different commands. Also Cygwin isn't Linux. Finally I can't reproduce the problem. `ls > File.txt` lists one file per line for me under Cygwin. So does `ls -1`. My guess is that your problem is that you're viewing the output using Notepad or some other program that doesn't understand the Unix-style line endings (LF) that Cygwin uses and instead expects Windows-style line endings (CF LF).

Comment: I am viewing it with Notepad, so that's a likely possibility. Is there an option for `ls` that can work around that?

Comment: @Hashim: run `todos` or `unix2dos` on the output file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

redirecting output of `ls` to `File.txt`will result of one file per line. thus, your command is correct. you can verify this on bash using `cat File.txt`.

probably, you are viewing the output file on notepad. please view it on notepad++ and you will see it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

When output of `ls` doesn't go to terminal, it displays one file per line, so

```
ls > List.txt
```

should be correct.

`-a` includes "hidden" files, i.e. files whose names start with a dot. I'm not sure whether `dir /b` lists hidden files or not.

`ls -1` should list one file per line. If it doesn't, could you please post the type and version of your OS, and output of `ls --version`?

Comment: Added some more details to the question. I'm using `bash` on Windows 7 with Cygwin. Bash version is 4.4.12(3). `ls -1` works for the console, but has no effect when outputting to files.